# Cache - How to use it? (in firebase for a beginner)

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I as a beginner struggle a lot to figure out how you can save reads of data which is constantly queried. Does anybody has some good resources to learn about this. Currently I have a list of exercises, which is frequently refreshed, but the reads are much more compared to the writes. I set it up on firestore and always serve it through ejs (template engine) to my modal. Instead of always querying the same data all the time to my template, can I save the results and just serve them? I could also serve it statically, which wouldn't be so dynamic as it's made by hand. But I could then save a lot of reads and just query the newly added (creation Date after I implemented the data static),or?

In my project I am using just plain HTML and plain JavaScript (Cloud Functions with express)

Is there no common practice for this kind of situation? You could also save the data like every hour on Google cloud platform as a JSON tree and then read it from there? Would save a lot of reads or you could make something like a load more button, where only the first 20 results are loaded ( but this would make the user experience a little tricky and not so likable..)